# Limit of a function with two variables existance

Tags: calculus

I have the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{y^2}e^{\frac{-x^2}{y}}$, and I have to show whether the following limit exists: $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$.  If I set $y=x$, then $\lim\limits_{(x,x)\to(0,0)}f(x,x)=\lim\limits_{x \to 0}f(x,x)=0$; and if I set $y=x^2$ the limit does not exist. Is this enough to say that the $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ does not exist?

Comment: Yes. You are choosing 2 different paths, and both give you different results. Therefore it does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is correct since

- $x=0 \implies \frac{x^3}{y^2}e^{\frac{-x^2}{y}}=0$
- $y=x^2 \quad x\to 0^+ \implies \frac{x^3}{y^2}e^{\frac{-x^2}{y}}=\frac{1}{xe}\to +\infty$

the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you sure that the limit in the second case is +infinity? I ask because $x->0$ but we don't know is it bigger or less than zero.

Comment: @spyer note that I've declared $y=x^2\to 0^+$ but of course we can reach the same conclusion claiming that for$ x\to 0\quad \lim \frac{1}{xe}$ doesn't exist. That's  a minor issue which doesn't change the conclusion.

Comment: @spyer anyway you are right I've indicated that for $x^2$ then it is not correct! I fix that

Comment: OK, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If the limit exists, let it be $c$. Then for a given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x,y)-c|<\epsilon \quad \forall \quad |x|<\delta,|y|<\delta$.

Hence, taking $y=x^2$ in particular, we can choose $0<\delta_1<\delta$ such that $|x|<\delta_1 \implies x^2<\delta$.

Thus we have, $|f(x,x^2)-c|<\epsilon \quad \forall \quad |x|<\delta_1$.
Which means $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x,x^2)$ exists and this gives a contradiction.